# MyEclipse Blue 10.7 mistakenly including referenced Java library jars in war

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, shared-libraries, war

I have 4 referenced libraries on my Java Build path for my Java Project in MyEclipse Blue 10.7.  My understanding is that one of the points of using referenced libraries was so that they are **not** included in the final war file when it is built and deployed.  However, in my case all of the jars in these 4 referenced libraries are indeed being included in the lib folder in my final war file when it is built and deployed.

Is my assumption about how referenced libraries work wrong, or is there a setting or something to keep referenced library jars from being included in the war file?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'd suggest using a proper build tool (Eclipse is primarily an IDE) such as Gradle, Maven, Ant, etc.

Comment: We do use Ant for builds, but that doesn't solve the question about the Eclipse behavior.  Eclipse didn't always behave this way and I'm trying to figure out why it is doing so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew there had to be a setting in Eclipse to control exactly what was included in the lib folder and my colleague found this [link](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/how-to-add-websphere-7-or-websphere-8-runtime-in-myeclipse/) that led to the answer; I'll post the details below for completeness.  However, I should be clear that I'm using MyEclipse Blue 10.7...not just Eclipse.  I'm going to edit my original post above stating such.  I'm sure there is a similar setting in Eclipse somewhere however.

- Go to Window >> Preferences >> MyEclipse >> Java Enterprise Project >> Web Project
- Go to the Deployment Tab
- Under Library Deployment Policies make sure that "Jars from User Libraries" is ***unchecked***

That's it.  Since that setting was checked the jars from my libraries were always being included in my lib folder in my war; in my case that was not the desired behavior.

Thanks to @vanje for getting me thinking with the comment thread above as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is false. According to the The Java EE Tutorial, section [5.3 Packaging Web Archives](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/packaging003.htm) the folder `WEB-INF/lib`

> [...] contains JAR files that contain enterprise beans, and JAR archives of libraries called by server-side classes

The usual case is that a WAR file contains all referenced libraries but not the JEE libraries like the servlet API itself. JEE libraries are provided by the servlet container.

So each webapplication running in a servlet container can have its own version of a library.

Comment: So in my case I have a bunch of IBM Websphere 8.5 jars that I am including on my build path in Eclipse as a referenced library.  Are you saying that it is the normal behavior of Eclipse to actually include all of those IBM jars in the lib folder in my war?

Comment: Hm, when I have a Dynamic Web Project and I export a WAR via right click on the project / Export / WAR file, then only the JARs located in the project under `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` are included. If I add a dependency via right click on project / Properties / Java Build Path / Libraries then this JAR will not be included in the WAR.

Comment: Hmmm...  One of the differences in our setup that I can see is that my project is just a "Web Project" and not a "Dynamic Web Project".  Could that be problematic?  If so, are there any settings I can change to my current Web Project to fix the issue?

Comment: Maybe this would help: [Converting static Web projects to dynamic Web projects](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwpcnvrt.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately I do not have a "Static Web Project" but rather just a "Web Project"...which, as I looked closer, actually originated from me creating a "Java Project" originally.  So that is a more accurate description of what I have now.  I apologize for the confusion!